# Java- give every instance of object an unique number

Tags: java, variables, object, numbers, final

I'm having trobule writing a simple program in java.

I have a class called ticket, where I have:

```
public class Ticket {
public String movieTitle = null;
public static Integer movieNumber = 0;
public final Integer currentMovieNumber;

public Ticket(String movieTitle) {
    currentMovieNumber = movieNumber++;
    this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
}
```

}

Now when I call the ticket out in another class and run the program to get the numbers of the id's, they're all the same. 
If I call out 3 tickets, every id/movieNumber is 3, when I call out 2 tickets, the id will be 2.
Can someone please help me with this ? I thought using static and final would help me but I guess there's is something I am missing.

Comment: You should be looking at `currentMovieNumber` for a particular instance, not `movieNumber`.

Comment: When I create 3 `Ticket`s, I get `currentMovieNumber`s of `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Comment: The *ID* of a movie is supposed to be `currentMovieNumber`. This should work as expected. @rgettman that's not what you want?

Comment: @Christian I'm just pointing out that `currentMovieNumber` seems correct to me.  It's possible, as Jon Skeet suggests, that the OP is looking at `movieNumber`, the `static` variable, and seeing `3` for all 3 `Ticket`s.

Comment: @rgettman sorry I thought you were the OP. And yes, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking at `movieNumber` from your other class, which isn't appropriate. I would write it like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Ticket {
    private static final AtomicInteger ticketCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    private final int ticketId;
    private final String movieTitle; // Or a reference to a Movie...

    public Ticket(String movieTitle) {
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        this.ticketId = ticketCounter.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getTicketId() {
        return ticketId;
    }

    public String getMovieTitle() {
        return movieTitle;
    }
}
```

Now that the fields are private, other classes *can't* look at the wrong value - instead, they can only get at the ID for a particular ticket, and the title. They have no business looking at the counter.

The downside of this is that you can't easily reset the counter, or resume it when you next run the program, etc. To achieve that, you might want a `TicketFactory` which has an *instance* field for the counter, and an instance method of `createTicket` which creates a ticket by assigning it the next ID etc. `Ticket` itself then wouldn't know about the counter.

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was that I used movieNumber instead of currentMmvieNumber. I will try to pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using wrapper classes, i.e. `Integer` instead of `int`, which means that inside the class field you are only storing the reference. That means that in your constructor you are actually linking each class' `currentMovieNumber` to the `static movieNumber` so that when you increment the `movieNumber`, since all the instances' numbers point to it, every `Ticket` will have the same incremented number.

Using `int` instead of `Integer` should solve this.