# Generating unique auto-incrementing instance IDs

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier, identifier

I have been trying to generate unique IDs for class instances starting from 1, like so:

```
public abstract class foo {
    static int ID = 0;
    final int id;

    public foo() { this.id = ++ID; }
}
```

I then realised that I have several classes that require this behaviour, and so I tried to make an `abstract class` from which to inherit, but I found that `static` fields can't really be inherited.

Is there any way I can reuse this common behaviour in Java?

*Edit:*
I did not make it clear, but I need the indexes for each subclass to be not only unique, but also consecutive.

For example, if I have `bar` and `baz` inheriting from `foo`:

```
bar b1 = new bar();
baz b2 = new baz();
bar b3 = new bar();
```

`b2` should have `id == 1`, and `b3` should have `id == 2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java- give every instance of object an unique number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708765/java-give-every-instance-of-object-an-unique-number)

Comment: No, it is generally done on a class by class basis (or on a hierarchy of classes). And you should not make an abstract class because you want a counter

Comment: @RC. This isn't a duplicate of that question. This question is about how to reuse the (already understood) behaviour across multiple classes.

Comment: @chiastic-security I don't see why not, see http://ideone.com/Nt8g5k

Comment: @RC. I edited my question. Actually, the behaviour you showed in your snippet is the problem I encountered while trying to inherit the abstract class. I need each subclass' ID to be consecutive with the subclass instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really! There are a couple of things you might try:

1. Have a single `IDGenerator` class with a static method to generate a new ID for a specific class. The `.generate()` method would take a `Class<?>` parameter, and would maintain a `HashMap` mapping classes to most recently given out identifiers. This would put all the logic into one class, but wouldn't really simplify things.
2. Have a static reference to a new instance of an `IDGenerator` class inside each class that wants to use this kind of behaviour. In this case, the `IDGenerator` class wouldn't need a `Class<?>` parameter because there would be one instance for each class using it. Its `.generate()` method would be a no-arg method. Again, I'm not sure this makes things much simpler.
3. Abandon the requirement for consecutive IDs. That way, you could have a class `IDGenerator` with a static no-arg `.generate()` method that would just dish out the next unused identifier. Your identifiers would then be unique across your application, and not consecutive within a class.

What you've got is pretty fool-proof and slimline.

One more minor note: you say you want your IDs to start from 0, but the way you've written it, they'll start from 1. You want `this.id = ID++` rather than `this.id = ++ID`.

Comment: It was a mistake. I actually meant that they are intended to start from 1. Edited accordingly. And thank you for understanding what I meant even though I was undesirably vague. I really wish I could upvote your answer.

Comment: @RedCat23 you don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but do click the tick to mark as accepted answer if it was useful (which will also give you some rep points).

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, this may not be a good idea. However, if you want to do it just increment the counter in the base class constructor:

```
abstract class foo {
    static int globalId = 0;
    final int id;
    foo() {
        id = globalId;
        ++globalId;
    }
}
```

Use an AtomicInteger if thread safety is a concern.

Comment: If I just increment the counter in the base class then all the subclasses will share the same ID generation, using the same `globalId`. That is not what I need.

Comment: Yes, all will share the same id generation, but each class will get a unique id. The globalId is static so there is only one for the entire program. Your question indicates all you need to guarantee is a unique number assigned to each instance and this does that. It sounds like maybe your requirement is more specific: that each subclass has integers that are unique **to the subclass** and that for each subclass the integers start and 0 and have no gaps. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need, for each subclass' IDs to be consecutive. Sorry for being vague. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

One option, use UUIDs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

```
UUID.randomUUID();
```

A second option is to just use AtomicInteger for this:

```
    AtomicInteger idGen = new AtomicInteger();
    System.out.println(String.format("First is %d", idGen.getAndIncrement()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Second is %d", idGen.getAndIncrement()));
```

I would not use abstract classes or inheritance or even custom classes for this issue.

EDIT: Here is a full example that supports the initial code. I don't see how you could make this simpler:

```
public static class foo {
    final public int id;

    foo(int id) { this.id = id; }
}

public static class bar extends foo {
    static final AtomicInteger idGen = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public bar() {
        super(idGen.getAndIncrement());
    }
}

public static class baz extends foo {
    static final AtomicInteger idGen = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public baz() {
        super(idGen.getAndIncrement());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    bar b1 = new bar();
    baz b2 = new baz();
    bar b3 = new bar();

    System.out.println(String.format("b1.id = %d", b1.id));
    System.out.println(String.format("b2.id = %d", b2.id));
    System.out.println(String.format("b3.id = %d", b3.id));
}
```

Comment: UUIDs are unnecessarily long. Using an `AtomicInteger` sounds desirable, but I am using an abstract class because I need to reuse that behaviour.

Comment: If you need to reuse the behavior, reuse AtomicInteger instances. Inheritance is a terrible and inappropriate mechanism for achieving reuse.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't create a new class when the standard JDK has a class that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Even if I replaced my incrementation with the atomic operation of `AtomicInteger`, I would still have the same problem. I need the ID generation to be performed automatically inside the constructor, but since I need this for several classes, I would need to redefine a different `AtomicInteger` for each class. In trying to follow the DRY principle, I want to place the common behaviour inside a parent class. That's my logic. The `AtomicInteger` doesn't do exactly what I need.

Comment: Add a static AtomicInteger instance to each participating class. bar and baz classes in your example would each have their own static class wide AtomicInteger instance.

Comment: But then I would have to repeat the constructor incrementation code in each participating class.

Comment: Yes, but it is just one line of code in the constructor. I dont see the inheritance route being simpler. Post simplified example code. I assume you would pass the id to the parent foo class.

Comment: The implementation would get too lengthy, but basically this should allow me to add things in the constructor based on `this.getClass()`, retrieving info from some sort of `Map<Class<?>, int>`.