# Subclasses of an abstract class should have progressive ids starting at 0 for each class

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass, junit4

I've spent an entire afternoon on this task that I really think is pretty easy to accomplish, but still I can't find where is my mistake.

Essentially what I have to do is having an abstract class which has to be the parent of two sub-classes, each one of them should have an ID starting at 0. Then test it using JUnit4 to see if it actually works.

I've tried to print out id values in main thread and it seems to work, but then when I try to use JUnit4 tests they only work partially (one test is good, the other is not).

Hopefully with an image of my code it should be easier to understand the task, I will really appreciate any help to spot the error. [You can find my code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAF1c.png)

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: These tests are not isolated, per se. So if one test runs (not in the order as in the test class, the order is determined by junit but you can probably force the order too), it will already increment the id of one object. So if another test uses the same object it already has the incremented id.

Comment: To fix what @qristjan mentioned, either create the objects in each test method, or create them in an `@Before` method, so they are created for each individual test.

Comment: Look at this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745402/generating-unique-auto-incrementing-instance-ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745402/generating-unique-auto-incrementing-instance-ids)

Comment: @qristjan I know that and indeed if I use a test file for each test case it works fine, but I still have to use a single Junit file with different test cases on it. I know it may sound wrong, but this is the assignament that I have.

Comment: @VolkanOrhan thank you, I had a quick look at the link you provided but this is not the same I want to accomplish here. I need each of the two subclasses to have a progressive id that starts at 0, not a unique id for the parent class.

Comment: @DavidConrad these two are the first fixes I tried to make, without any luck unfortunatly. The issue is still there. Even if I try to create the two objects in each test method or if I use the `@Before` annotation on a setUp method.

Comment: Yes, my earlier comment was mistaken. The problem is because of the static class variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to using a static variable to initialize the id. A static variable (class constant) exists in a single copy for all instances of the class. When you create the first instance of B, b1, classId has value 0, but when you assign it to id, it increases by 1. Consequently, when you create the second instance of B, b2, classId no longer goes 0, but starts from 1. You can solve by removing classId and assigning id the value 0 directly in the constructor. Or, you can assign id the value of classId, without increment. This definitely solves the reported problem, but it is not clear what you mean when you talk about progressive id. If the interpretation is that the instances of B must have a progressive id, then your code is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Btw instances of A and instances of B should have progressive ids, for example: Parent a0 = new A(""); ID=0 Parent a1 = new A(""); ID=1; Parent b0 = new B(""); ID=0; Parent b1 = new B(""); ID=1

Comment: For me your code works fine! Maybe you have problems with JUnit4? Try to insert the toString() method in all the classes and print the created objects in the main. You will see that the ids have the correct values.
A [id = 0, toString () = Parent [name = A1]]
B [id = 0, toString () = Parent [name = B1]]
B [id = 1, toString () = Parent [name = B2]]
For me works fine also Junit4 test.

Comment: Yes I've already tried to print the object in the main thread and indeed the code works fine there. But when it comes to Junit4 tests it doesn't, are you doing your test on a single file or have you created a Junit4 file for each test case?

Comment: I used only one file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time a test is run, a new instance of the test class is created, and new instances of the classes under test are created for its fields, which means the class variables for the IDs keep counting up. You can reset them to zero at the end of the test with an `@After` `tearDown` method, but you will need to access the private class variable via reflection.

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    Field classIdA = A.class.getDeclaredField("classId");
    classIdA.setAccessible(true);
    classIdA.setInt(null, 0);
    
    Field classIdB = B.class.getDeclaredField("classId");
    classIdB.setAccessible(true);
    classIdB.setInt(null, 0);
}
```

This way, once each unit test finishes running, it will reset the state of each subclass to the status quo ante.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you for your code. I tried it and it's doing its job. Do you think there is a way to achieve the same result without using reflection? Of course I mean changing the class declaration if needed.

Comment: @Gu160 Certainly. If the class had a public way to reset the counter, the `tearDown` method could simply call it. For instance, `public static void reset() { classId = 0; }`

Comment: @Gu160 Come to think of it, it could even be a protected method, or a package-private method, since the test class is in the same package: `static void reset() { classId = 0; }`